# Rsync fails when escaping parameters

Tags: unix, escaping, rsync, quotes

I am currently testing `rsync` in order to synchronize some file between two servers.

When I espace the parameters of my command line with single quote, `rsync` seems to failed:

```
'rsync' '--recursive' '--verbose' '--archive' '--copy-dirlinks' '--rsh="ssh -i /path/to/my/key"' '--delete' '/path/to/my/source/directory' 'user@server:/path/to/my/destination/directory'
```

> rsync: Failed to exec ssh -i /path/to/my/key: No such file or
>   directory (2) rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(85)
>   [sender=3.1.2] rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received
>   so far) [sender] rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream
>   (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.2]

But when I do not escape the parameters, `rsync` works correctly:

```
rsync --recursive --verbose --archive --copy-dirlinks --rsh="ssh -i /path/to/my/key" --delete /path/to/my/source/directory user@server:/path/to/my/destination/directory
```

I am using the 3.1.2 version.

I am doing something wrong ?

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: @Jakuje My command line is generated by an other software. Escaping can not be disabled.

Comment: I don't see how you are running the `rsync` from there, but you should be able either get rid of the "escaping" or pass them as an argument so they will get properly expanded.

Comment: Software that unconditionally adds single quotes to every parameter in a shell command line is going to cause problems with certain types of parameters that depend on shell metacharacters being properly evaluated, such as double quotes, `$`, and backquotes. In your case, quoting the `--rsh="..."` parameter will cause the double quotes to be passed through to the program. You need to either not quote that parameter or omit the double quotes.